Excel Macro only works when a certain workbook is open
I use this macro to fill selected cells with zero but I need to have the original workbook that it was created in open in order to run it.
Sub replaceBlankWithZero()

Dim rng As Range
Selection.Value = Selection.Value
For Each rng In Selection
If rng = "" Or rng = " " Then
rng.Value = "0"
Else
End If Next rng

End Sub

I'm not sure how to change it to work on all workbooks without having to open the original.

Well, the macro is literally embedded in the original spreadsheet it has been saved with so it only works when the original spreadsheet is opened.  Just copy it to all other relevant spreadsheets.

You can store it in your personal workbook. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790
